# Html , frameset and youtube player on local pc . can i build nested frameset just form 1 html

Tags: html, youtube, youtube-api, frameset-iframe

can i load youtube page in frame set html ? or iframe ?
so it will load the youtube page in one frame and my local html file in the other frame.
this code dosnt work :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  >
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:100%">
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/" width="100%" height="300">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

second question is , can i build nested frame set just form 1 html ?
so 1 html will be the YouTube site and the second frame will be my html.
but not loading external file , just using itself?

Comment: Do you want to load the entire youtube page or just the video?  Yes you could use iframes to load them side by side, I wouldn't necessarily recommend it as I don't like iframes but it would work.

Comment: i added example with iframe that doesn't work, its not from server , i just load it from file -> open in firefox

Answer (score 0):

YouTube pages are built using the HTML5 standard - both `<frame>` and `<frameset>` have been depreciated and are not compatible with HTML 5.

What this means, is that including a YouTube page won't work within a frameset.  You can embed the video player, but not the entire web page.  To embed the video (in an iframe) you click on the "Share" link and follow the instructions on YouTube.

If you have any existing `<frameset>` fields pointing to YouTube (or any other public sites) you need to look at replacing these sooner rather than later.